# HBase update operation

Tags: hbase

1. I am new to HBase, I find in HBase client API, update operation is not supported? Is that correct?
2. If so, what is the suggested best practices to update the values for a specific rowkey?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use PUT which will create or update the value of any cell.
You **don't** need to use delete unless you want the new version to not have some of the old cells .

say we have

```
r1:f1:c1:value1
r1:f1:c2:value2
```

you can put r1:f1:c1 new value  and you'd get:

```
r1:f1:c1:new value 
r1:f1:c2:value2
```

Note that actually each cell is stored as rowkey, column family, cell, timestamp, version and value. So depending on how you set versioning (per column family) you can also access the old values including doing a point in time query to see deleted values.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is clear, and helped me better understand HBase (which I'm only barely starting to investigate).

Comment: Hi @Arnon, my question is more about how to update in atomic way. I want to make read (GET) and update in an atomic operation sequence. Supposing in a case how to update is dependent on the value read, so I want to avoid any update between read and update. In your sample, how to achieve the goal?

Comment: you can use checkAndPut or checkAndDelete in the HTable API http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndPut(byte[], byte[], byte[], byte[], org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put)

Comment: @tonio HBase is an "append only" store. this is why HBase does comapactions from time to time (something you need to be aware of and control see section on splitting/compation in http://hbase.apache.org/book/important_configurations.html )

Comment: Thanks @Amon, checkAndPut could guarantee concurrent operations by multiple clients are atomic? I mean for example client A is calling checkAndPut, and client B is also calling checkAndPut at the same time, each of the operations are atomic (e.g. after client A check and before client A Put, no values are changed by client B)?

Comment: Yes. HBase provide atomicity for operations on a single row - see http://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want to do is perform a Put operation.
You can look at the HBase's [Put API client docs](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html) as well as this blog post titled: [Java Example Code using HBase Data Model Operations](http://autofei.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/java-example-code-using-hbase-data-model-operations/) for some examples, and descriptions of the operations.

To update a row, you will have to issue a sequence of "Delete" and "Put", in a single Mutation, so they are seen as an update externally.

See the [Class RowMutations documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/RowMutations.html) on how to build such a call.

Comment: Hi tonio, correct me if I am wrong. I do not see any Put API support update operation or in the sample code. For update I mean, there is already a row in an HBase table, for example, row key is r1, and it has one column called c1 and there is value in the cell r1/c1. For update I mean I want I want to change the value for the cell r1/c1 to some other values. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right, if you want to change the values in a row, you have to combine delete and put in an atomic call. See updated answer.