# Trying to understand updates in HBase

Tags: hbase

I have read in the below links that HBase does not support updates which say that HBase is an "append only" store.

[HBase update operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667901/hbase-update-operation/13685752)

[HBase update operations on hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677201/hbase-update-operations-on-hdfs)

Also, I am aware that one can update existing cell value in HBase using the put command by just following the same syntax and mentioning the new value.

For example, one can do as below to update the value of city column from 'Boston' to 'Chicago':

```
put 'emp','row1','personal:city','Chicago'
```

when the previous row was:

```
row1 column = personal:city, timestamp = 1418275907, value = Boston
```

In HBase, one can enable versioning for a column family and have multiple values which can have same "row key + column family + column qualifier" values. One can use PUT which will create or update the value of any cell. Upon doing versioning one can also access the old values as mentioned in the below post:

Based on these, I have the below doubts:

1. Why is it said that HBase does not support updates when one can update as shown above ( as in example above where city value is updated from 'Boston' to 'Chicago') ?
2. HBase does versioning by keeping previous versions too. What is the reason for keeping previous values too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it said that HBase does not support updates when one can update as shown above

It is true that HBase does not support update operations explicitly. The updates like the way you described is only an effect of a *put* operation.

> HBase does versioning by keeping previous versions too. What is the reason for keeping previous values too?

HBase keeps multiple versions of records only if you ask it to do so. By default it would keep only 1 version of the record which is essential like an un-versioned store. The *get* and *scan* operations usually fetch only latest version of the record. More about it [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema.versions.max).

Lets say, we have a empty table with a column family that's configured to keep last 3 versions of the record. We perform 3 *put* operation at different timestamps t=x.

```
put 'a','myrow','d:mood','happy' // at t=1
put 'a','myrow','d:mood','sad'   // at t=2
put 'a','myrow','d:mood','bored' // at t=3
```

At this point the data stored in the corresponding HFile for rowkey *myrow* would look similar to this (illustrative only)

```
row_key | timestamp |  value
myrow   | 1         | d:mood=happy
myrow   | 2         | d:mood=sad
myrow   | 3         | d:mood=bored
```

Now if you perform a *get* operation for rowkey *myrow*, it would by default only fetch d:mood=bored since that has the highest timestamp value and thereby is the latest version of the record. We could see that the old records haven't been updated by our *put* operations. This is what is meant when they say HBase does not support updates. Only new record are being created and thereby giving us the illusion that the record is being updated by our *put* operations. In this case If we continue to perform another *put* operation on the same rowkey the oldest version of the record would be invalidated(since we configured only for 3 max versions to keep) and would be removed in the next compaction cycle.

Comment: Thanks.Understood that HBase doesnt support update explicitly but only using put. What is the reason that it has been designed to not support it explicitly? Understood that it keeps 1 version by default and can be configured to keep more versions and by default get will fetch the one with latest timestamp.For what scenario would it be required to keep multiple versions? Upvoting the answer.

Comment: HBase is designed to run on top of HDFS which by design does not support update operations for the stored blocks. Keeping multiple versions of records could be advantageous when you need a historical view of the record.